# Non guessable CloudFront URL

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront, cdn, pre-signed-url

I'm wondering if there's a way to make the S3 path unguessable.
Let's suppose I have an S3 path like this: https://s3-bucket.com/singer/album/song/song.mp3, this file will be served through CloudFront, so the path will be: https://cloundfront-dist-id.com/singer/album/song/song.mp3?signature=... (I'm using signed URLs). My question is : it is possible to make the /singer/album/song/song.mp3 not guessable by hashing it using for example Lambda or Lambda@Edge function so the client will see a url like this https://cloundfront-dist-id.com/some_hash?signature=... (same as Spotify)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your actual goal (that is, _what_ are you wanting to achieve, rather than _how_)? If you are using pre-signed URLs, why do you want to make the URL 'unguessable'?

Comment: I know that it's won't add a security to the url, but I'm just curious about how they're doing it.

Comment: Only Spotify developers could answer "how".  It's probably that they name objects in their storage system based off some globally unique ID from some DB engine, and that ID is used to push objects, but who knows?  This is a design decision based on other factors, there is no security to be gained here.

Comment: @AnonCoward, thanks for your answer. I thought about a solution like this by generating a unique Id for each song and then push it to a storage service like S3, the problem with this solution is that if you have 8 million songs then you have to create 8 million buckets so you will lose the ability to organise the songs based on their album, artist...

Comment: 8 million objects, not buckets, but yes, if you care about organization in S3 by object key, then this won't work.  I doubt a service like Spotify cares about such things.

Comment: @AnonCoward yes sorry you're right, object not bucket

Comment: @AmineAISSAOUI Did you find a solution? Share me if you find

Comment: @HimalAcharya, I think that they're calculating the hash (probably a sha2) function of the song metadata, it could be something like sha256(album+artist_name+song_name), then the song is pushed to the bucket using this hash as the song name.

Comment: It means you need two bucket one with hash name and other with real path @AmineAISSAOUI